# embed silverlight into durandal

Tags: silverlight, durandal

I have a silverlight excel component I need to embed in my durandal application.

My HTML looks like:

```
   <form id="silverlightControl" runat="server" data-bind="if: silverlightIsInstalled() && silverlightData()!=null">
        <div id="silverlightControlHost">
            <object id="silverlightObject" data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%">
                <param name="source" value="ClientBin/SilverlightGrid.xap" />
                <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
                <param name="onLoad" value="onSilverlightLoad" />
                <param name="background" value="white" />
                <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="5.0.61118.0" />
                <param name="autoUpgrade" value="false" />
            </object><iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe>
        </div>
    </form>
```

The problem is this tries to call a global functions called onSilverlightLoad and onSilverlightError.

Is there a way from within my module, to define and overwrite these global functions?

Comment: Replace them with your own?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I call a javascript function once a silverlight control has finished loading?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452604/how-do-i-call-a-javascript-function-once-a-silverlight-control-has-finished-load)

Comment: this is not a duplicate. See the code above already has the <param name="onLoad" value="onSilverlightLoad" /> parameter, but the other question does not address how to define this function in require.js AMD modules for single page app frameworks like durandal where there are no global variables

Comment: Yes I need to define and replace with my own. With the code above Silverlight calls the onSilverlightLoad function, each AMD durandal module I have needs to overwrite this so that the functions relevant to the current page are executed.

Comment: So... You want to run server side code from a JavaScript function?  Please define what your "module" is.  I do understand why you just don't change the parameter to your own JavaScript function and run with it.

Comment: No. Nothing about my question has anything to do with server side. The context of my question is Durandal (see title). I am talking about a require.js AMD module.

Comment: Sorry, judging by the accepted answer, I didn't understand the difficulty or what was misunderstood about doing what he did.  It seemed basic to me so I thought I was missing something.

Comment: Where do you guys normally put code that needs to run in global scope in durandal? I used the started kit then edited the script tag in Durandal/Index.cshtml, is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way from within my module, to define and overwrite these
>   global functions?

yes, you could do something like this...

in global scope:

```
var currentModule = null;

function onSilverlightLoad(sender, args) {
   if (currentModule && currentModule.onSilverlightLoad) {
       // forward the event to the current module
       currentModule.onSilverlightLoad(sender, args);
       return;
   }
   // fallback logic...
}

function onSilverlightError(sender, args) {
   if (currentModule && currentModule.onSilverlightError) {
       // forward the event to the current module...
       currentModule.onSilverlightError(sender, args);
       return;
   }
   // fallback logic...
}
```

in your module:

```
window.currentModule = this;
// todo: define public function properties named onSilverlightLoad and onSilverlightError
```

Answer (score 0):

Tip for anyone else embedding silverlight into a Durandal app.

You need to do this, or when you leave that page and return to it, bad things will happen:

vm.binding = function () {
    return { cacheViews: false };
};